# WPF VisualState - "Pressed" event will not fire

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager

I am playing around with XAML ControlTemplates for the first time and am having a strange time with one basic animation I am working on.

In the style below, the Pressed visualstate will absolutely not trigger the ScaleTransform. If I change Pressed to Focused or MouseOver, it works just fine.

What am I missing?

```
      <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
          <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.BorderBrush}" />
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                      <Border x:Name="Button_Border"
                              Background="{StaticResource Button.BackgroundBrush}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Padding="5,2,5,2"
                              CornerRadius="2">
                          <Border.RenderTransform>
                              <ScaleTransform x:Name="Button_ScaleTransform"
                                              CenterX="0.5"
                                              CenterY="0.5" />
                          </Border.RenderTransform>
                          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                              <VisualStateGroup>
                                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />


                                  <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                      <Storyboard>
                                          <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Button_Border"
                                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX">
                                              <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.9" />
                                          </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                          <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Button_Border"
                                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY">
                                              <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.9" />
                                          </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                      </Storyboard>
                                  </VisualState>


                                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                  <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                              </VisualStateGroup>
                          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                          <ContentPresenter />
                      </Border>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the empty Focused event, which on a Button is only fired when it is clicked, was overriding the Pressed event. By simply deleting the empty Focused event, the Pressed event began working.