# Xamarin WPF - Button Pressed event not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I follow this article [WPF platform setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf) to setup WPF for Xamarin. I successfully run Xamarin for WPF, everything works fine, except [the Pressed event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/button#pressing-and-releasing-the-button) for ImageButton won't fire.

Here is Nuget Package version I installed:

```
Base Xamarin Project
NETStandard.Library version="2.0.3"
Xamarin.Essentials version="1.6.1"
Xamarin.Forms version="5.0.0.2012"

--------------------------------
Android Project
Xamarin.Essentials version="1.6.1"
Xamarin.Forms version="5.0.0.2012"

--------------------------------
WPF Project
OpenTK version="3.0.1"
OpenTK.GLControl version="3.0.1"
Xamarin.Forms version="5.0.0.2012"
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF" version="5.0.0.2012" 
===============
.Net Framwork 4.7.2
```

Here is my code (Base Xamarin Project):

MainPage.xaml

```
<ImageButton Source="XamarinLogo.png"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    x:Name="imgBtn_Test" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
imgBtn_Test.Pressed += Test_Pressed;
imgBtn_Test.Released += Test_Released;

private void Test_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test_Pressed");//This does NOT work :(
}
private void Test_Released(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test_Released");//This works :)
}
```

When I start the WPF project, only the Test_Released() is called, Test_Pressed() isn't called at all.

I have noticed this issue when I use [ImageButton visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton#imagebutton-visual-states) and this feature only works on Android, not WPF, so I knew the Pressed event is broken for WPF, but that time it didn't matter because it's only visual, I can live with that, but this time I need the Pressed event to work on WPF because now it's function related.

How can I make Test_Pressed() work on my WPF project?

**Update:**

I can be sure that this issue is WPF's fault. I have tested my code on Android and it works as expected, only WPF doesn't work. I think I should edit the WPF project to make the WPF's Pressed event work properly.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41911266/4608491)

> (in WPF) Focused event, which on a Button is only fired when it is
> clicked, was overriding the Pressed event.

Maybe if I figure it out how to stop WPF from overriding Pressed with Focused, then I can fix this.

Comment: Did you try the `Clicked` event?

Comment: @mm8 - Clicked & Released event work, only Pressed event doesn't work.

Comment: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41911266/4608491 `(in WPF) Focused event, which on a Button is only fired when it is clicked, was overriding the Pressed event.` Maybe if I figure it out how to stop WPF from overriding Pressed with Focus, then I can fix this.

Comment: Why do you need `Pressed` when you have `Clicked`?

Comment: @mm8 - Many feature requires Pressed: e.g The Turbo button (you know, like the NES turbo buttons, you can hold the button and the button auto fire for you).